# Undo overwrite of built-in function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, built-in

I managed to redefine the built-in function `vector` by mistake.

More specifically, this is what I did:

```
(def vector [1 2 3 4 5 6])
```

And this is what I intended to do:

```
(def my-vector (vector 1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

Is there some way to "undo" that mistake, without restarting the REPL?

I.e., reverting `vector` back to its default definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(def vector #'clojure.core/vector)`